# Can I get three roots $a'$, $b'$ and $c'$ such that $P(x)=(x-a')(x-b')(x-c')$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

> If I have $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=1$ ($a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$) for the polynomial
>   $P(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)-1$, can I get three roots $a'$, $b'$ and $c'$
>   such that $P(x)=(x-a')(x-b')(x-c')$?

This is only a personal question I asked myself in relation to a question from a PUTNAM competition (preparation).

Should I use the Viete formula to answer this question? Does someone could advise me on this?

Comment: Certainly the polynomial $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) -1$ has three roots in $\mathbb{C}$ and they are functions of $a,b,c$ but I think that, in the general case, we have to solve the cubic to find these functions. And they are not, in general, integers (use $x(x-1)(x+1)-1$ to test this).

Comment: I'm not sure what the Q is.  If P(x)=1 for 3 distinct integers then (1) do you want to know whether P(x)=0 MUST have 3 distinct integer roots, or (2) do you want to know whether that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

a simple counter example is
$$
x(x-1)(x+1)-1=0
$$
that has not integer solutions and can be solved only with Cardano formulas.